# Can we remove old Jobs message notifications from the inbox?

Tags: support, jobs, notifications, global-inbox

Since Stack Overflow Jobs has been shut down, can we remove the old notifications from the inbox? Clicking on them just goes to the Jobs page saying that it has been shut down and has no other action.

[image: example job message notification]

Comment: What's the nature of these messages?

Comment: @CaveJohnson just messages from recruiters/employers that reached out.

Comment: I assume these are just really old notifications you got before the shutdown that are still appearing in your inbox?

Comment: Thats what it looks like in the screenshot @V2Blast, I see august 4, '21 and july 29, '21.

Comment: Yea they are old, I'm just not as active I suppose . I know they'll go away naturally, but just figured I'd ask.